# Canvas rendering once, after all actions

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

A little confused with one moment, appreciate any help.

I'm making an app, that uses canvas for rendering game board.
And I faced a problem that its not optimal, rendering canvas for each little change.

Here's what the structure is at the moment:

```
function renderCanvas() {
  // calling for each row
}

function renderRow() {
  // calling for each cell
}

function renderCell() {
  // Here i use FillRect and StrokeRect both
}
```

Functions cooperate with passing context to each other.

Now it renders each cell. And using beginPath appears to deal only with stroke.

I wonder if i can startPath (like beginPath) somehow in renderCanvas function and after all operations with context are done - i could render that all once?

Comment: You can only do one styling per `beginPath`, so if your cells require different colors, fonts, opacities then you must do a beginPath for each different style (but you can group same-styles together into one beginPath).

Comment: Thanks, this information was exactly the one i was looking for. You may post full answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can only do one styling per beginPath...**

So if your cells require different colors, fonts, opacities then you must do a beginPath for each different style (but you can group same-styles together into one beginPath).